# Ajax not sending proper success back

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have the below Ajax function

```
ajax = function (params, action) {        
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST", 
        url: "ajax.php", 
        data : params+"&action="+action,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response) {
            switch(action)
              {
                case "save":            
                    //some stuff
                    break;

                case "del":             
                    var seclastRow = $("."+table+" tr").length;
                    if(response.success == 1)
                     {                            
                       $("."+table+" tr[id='"+response.id+"']").effect("highlight",{color: '#f4667b'},500,function()
                       {
                        $("."+table+" tr[id='"+response.id+"']").remove();
                      });
                      }
                    break;
                  }
        },
        error: function() { 
            alert("Unexpected error, Please try again");
        }
    });
}
```

The following is the `ajax.php` that it calls. The file is a big if-else series, but I am pasting the wrong part only.

```
else if ($action == "del")
{    
    $id = $_POST['rid'];
    $res = $obj->delete_record($id);
    if ($res)
    {
        echo json_encode(array("success" => "1","id" => $id));
    }
    else
    {
        echo $obj->error("delete");
    }
}
```

However, once the result is echoed back, the success function never enters in the Ajax part and I always get the Unexpected error alert.

Any ideas?

I as able to get the error using the callback `error: function()` and then displaying the response inside console.log. Check the image. [response text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brZOw.png)

Comment: What are you actually getting back from the server? Is it an error message? What does it say? (You can look at the server's response using your browser's developer console and looking at the network tab.

Comment: If the `error` handler is being hit it means that the server is not returning a `200 OK` response and the error is in your PHP code. You can find the exact cause of the error by checking the request and its response in the network tab of the console.

Comment: Also note that the `switch` in your JS code is missing a closing `}`

Comment: are you sure there is no error without ajax?

Comment: yes, because I am able to check the database manually and it is added. so it means the php is working fine. at least the addition or the removal part. check my updated part.

Comment: I'm not sure, but it is the data a valid json?

Comment: @JeroenBellemans The json i am getting back from the php is : {"success":"1","id":"22"} which is valid

Comment: It could also be some **json parsing** error. Have you tried to analyse the response like @Terminus said?

Comment: @Terminus @oniramarf I am not getting anything from the server. I am getting the json `{"success":"1","id":"22"}` but my code is not entering the success: function(response) { } part, rather it goes error: function()

Comment: That's xdebug formatting a php message. You have some kind of php error on your page. If you click the network tab in your dev console then, click XHR, you'll be able to see all information about your ajax requests. Including a preview of the response as HTML. Looking at that will get your answer.

Comment: @Terminus I found the problem. I was using deprecated methods of mysql. so the warning was being parsed in the result. issue resolved :)